# How to hide elements based on user in FireBase and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm starting to use Firebase with AngularJS.
Coming from a php/serverside rendered pages.

I dont't get how we're supposed to hide parts of an app to some users.
I have basically 3 levels of users (guests / members / admins)
I could hide with a ng-show based on user, but this only hides client-side.
Data is still sent to the user

#### Real life example:

The menu items are different based on user level.
I was thinking about using ngshow and check for the uuid , but then again, is exposing the admins uuid a good idea? sounds terrible to me.

Then I thought about putting the menu inside a database and requesting the elements.
Not all users would access all items, but this means a lot of 'unauthorised access attempts on purpose'

What is the correct way of handling this? I feel like I've missed something important about client-only apps relying on Firebase services.

Comment: I think you should use authentication and send the user role on every request...and expose data according to the role of the user

Comment: yes, but how should I expose data? where can I code this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at userStatus method in service layer and it usage in other layers.

Service layer :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  loginGoogle() {

    this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider())
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert('Please try again');
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.fireAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  userStatus() {
    return this.fireAuth.authState;
  }
}
```

Navbar Component :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private authservice: AuthService) {
    this.user = this.authservice.userStatus();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.authservice.loginGoogle();
  }

  logout() {
    this.authservice.logout();
  }
}
```

And here is Navbar view, where you want to hide or show the elements based on if user is authenticated :

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Firebase</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid" routerLink="/listings">Listings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid" routerLink="/add-listing">Add Listing</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="!(user | async)?.uid" (click)="login()">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-link" *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid">
        <img src="{{(user | async)?.photoURL}}" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
        <br> Email: {{(user | async)?.email}}
        <br> Name: {{(user | async)?.displayName}}
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```